# Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell...texttospeech.googleapis.com

Tags: c#, google-apps-script, google-text-to-speech

please help with this issue, I don't understand why I don't have permission.

Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=PermissionDenied, Detail="Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the texttospeech.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.")'

Comment: Please copy and paste this error message instead of adding link to image - this will help keep good quality of Stack Overflow posts (for example post content will be searchable)

Answer (score 0):

This is telling you that you've authorized using, for example, `gcloud auth login` rather than using a proper service account for authorization.

It would be helpful to know what you were doing when you hit this error as well, as we'd be able to give you more specific details around the best way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know team, but after some time the service start to work, sorry I don't have the solution but it's working.
The gcloud was ok with the correct auth.